# Wordpress plugin names WP Job manager has issue while adding new job

Tags: wordpress

Since today morning, I'm unable to add a new job in WP-Job Manager plugin on my website.When I’m trying to add a new job it’s showing me “The editor has encountered an unexpected error.”

```
    TypeError: Unable to get property 'show_ui' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/editor.min.js?ver=9.2.5:17:119536)
   at i (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js?ver=4.17.11:6:91)
   at An.filter (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js?ver=4.17.11:99:320)
   at Anonymous function (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/editor.min.js?ver=9.2.5:17:119498)
   at Td (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:82:9)
   at hi (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:102:383)
   at Qg (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:144:211)
   at Rg (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:145:74)
   at Sc (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:158:109)
   at Z (http://networkinn.co.in/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.8.4:156:492)
```

Clicking on attempt recovery, is redirecting me to same page. Issue started before the update of WP Job manager. Then I also updated it. It still not resolved.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like a conflict with wp core files, do you have updated wp installation as well?

Comment: No!! I didn't even touch it. any insights on how can I solve it? @EaridA.

Comment: I'm using the latest version. Didn't update it after.

Comment: You can try activate Classic Editor plugin, if this not work sorry I don't know other solution. Have to wait for another community member.

Comment: @EaridA. You've solved the issue!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to know, your issue is fixed.